how to fix pictures overlapping the navbar while scrolling?
I'm currently working on a website for my school and I'm having the problem that whenever I scroll down the images go over my navbar.
I am a complete beginner and have no idea where the problem could be or how to fix it. I've already watched a few tutorials but I can't find the right answer to my question.
I already tryed out things like fixed positions and any kind of z-index but it doesnt works:
Can someone help me?


body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  background: #DCdCdC
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 650;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 400px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20em;
  float: right;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="fashion" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>fashion</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_2_Seite.css" media="all" />

</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <a href="1-Seite.html" class=l ogo>fashion</a>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="1-Seite.html">Home</a>
      <a href="2-Seite.html">Shop</a>
      <a href="#">Über uns</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="bb.hoodie.png" width="70%;">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="bbjacke.png" width="70%;">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="nfs.hose.png" width="70%;">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="ro.coat 2.png" width="70%;">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="nfs.bomber.png" width="70%;">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="ro.coat.png" width="70%;">
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>



I know its a lot but I would appreciate some help.

It seems to work just fine when you add the z-index to the header to lift it up above content that follows it in HTML, since you already have it positioned (fixed) so it got stacking context.


body {
   
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";

}


.header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding:19px 20px;
    background: #DCdCdC;
    z-index: 1;
}
    
.logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding:20px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 650;
}

.navbar a {

    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: 600; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    margin-left: 400px;
    word-spacing: 2px;

    
}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
    position: relative;
    bottom:-20em;
    float: right;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding:10px;
    
    img {
        background-color: maroon;
    }
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.row {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
}
<header class="header">
            <a href= "1-Seite.html" class= logo>fashion</a>
            <nav class="navbar">
                <a href="1-Seite.html">Home</a>
                <a href="2-Seite.html">Shop</a>
                <a href="#">Über uns</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="bb.hoodie.png" width="70%;">
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <img src="bbjacke.png" width="70%;">
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <img src="nfs.hose.png" width="70%;">
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <img src="ro.coat 2.png" width="70%;">
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <img src="nfs.bomber.png" width="70%;">
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <img src="ro.coat.png" width="70%;">
        </div>
    </div>



